# Which symmetry group is that?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider objects $T$ with elements arranged in a matrix-like fashion:

$$T=\begin{matrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i
\end{matrix}$$

I'd like to consider collections of such objects for certain choices of $a,b,...,i$ such that their set is collectively invariant under the following transformations:

- Cyclically rotate all entries within each $T$ up or down (periodicity 3).
- Cyclically rotate all entries within each $T$ left or right (periodicity 3).
- Reflect all entries within each $T$ along the middle row (periodicity 2).
- Reflect all entries within each $T$ along the middle column (periodicity 2).
- Reflect all entries within each $T$ along the proper diagonal (periodicity 2).
- Reflect all entries within each $T$ along the anti-diagonal (periodicity 2).

Now I wonder, which particular symmetry group are we talking about here?
Thanks for any suggestion!

PS:

I was thinking of a direct product of two dihedral groups (cyclic rotations and reflections), but the above case has more operations than that due to the reflections along diagonals being present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has order $72$, and it is is a wreath product of $S_3$ with $S_2$.

So it has $S_3 \times S_3$ as a normal subgroup of index $2$ (that is the direct product of dihedral groups that you observed), where the two direct factors are interchanged by conjugation by elements outside of this normal subgroup.

Comment: Wow, how did you count the order and then concluded the group from it?

Comment: Well the diagonal reflections are essentially interchanging rows and columns, so they interchange the two subgroups that are permuting the rows and the columns respectively. (I did check the calculation on the computer and the six permutations do indeed generate a subgroup of $S+9$ of order $72$.)

Comment: Could you tell me more about the software you are using on the computer and how you do the check? I'd like to learn how to do this myself for other examples. :)